# dataTable fnReloadAjax parameter skipping one parameter

Tags: jquery, datatables

I am working with dataTables. 
I am using the `fnReloadAjax` method to reload the data in the datatable. 
I have a need to send in a callback.

The `fnReloadAjax function` is defined as following.

```
$.fn.dataTableExt.oApi.fnReloadAjax = function ( oSettings, sNewSource, fnCallback, bStandingRedraw )
```

I called the function as following:

```
oTable.fnReloadAjax(oTable.oSetting,undefined,myCallback)
```

But when i debug the code i get the following result

```
$.fn.dataTableExt.oApi.fnReloadAjax = function ( oSettings, sNewSource, fnCallback, bStandingRedraw )

the oSetting have the right value.
sNewSource is not showing anything. 
the fnCallback is undefined. 
bStandingRedraw contains myCallback
```

I can get the code to work if i call it by

```
oTable.fnReloadAjax(oTable.oSetting,myCallback)
```

then the `fnCallback` and `myCallback` is mapped to eachother.

But i cant get into my head how a function can have a definition of 4 in parameters but when we are calling it its like the second argument is not there.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

One idea that i have is that the

```
oSettings
```

vairable contains information about the

```
sNewSource
```

Can one variable/object contain information that fills in other parameters in the call?